# How to learn Elasticsearch login and password

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm writing a site on Flask, connected by Elasticsearch, but when I log in to

```
http: // localhost: 9200
```

in the browser after connecting to it
a window appears with the fields "username" and "password"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZdSE.png)

if I close this window, the following appears on the page:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception",
"reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]",
"header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","ApiKey"]}}],
"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]",
"header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}
```

and accordingly the connection to Elasticsearch disappears

Where can I find this data to connect?

Comment: Could you please share your ES version?

Comment: If you have access to elasticsearch.yml file you can set and see the password there.

Comment: I have version 8.2.3

Comment: Check your elasticsearch.yml file in root of your ES installation folder.